# Webfonts Not Displaying in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, webfonts

I'm using two weights of Trade Gothic from MyFonts.com and I have it working in every browser except IE 8 and older. I have two css files - the main css and the css for the web fonts linked to every page in a template.

Here's the css for the web fonts.

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/27a4d8");


@font-face {font-family: 'TradeGothicLT-Light';
src: url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_0_0.eot');
src: url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
     url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}


@font-face {font-family: 'TradeGothicLT-Bold';
src: url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_1_0.eot');
src: url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_1_0.woff') format('woff'),
     url('new/css/fonts/27A4D8_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

I've tried redownloading the web font kit with different options and adding this to the htaccess but still no luck.

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
```

I've used this font with the same code on a different website and it works on older browsers. The font files are identical for both sites.